# Facing reflection error while tryinng to get types of assembly

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dll

I am facing issue while trying to get Types from assembly.

Here is my code:

```
Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(file.FullName));
Type type = assembly.GetTypes();
```

Facing issue only with below dlls.

EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework.dll

Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin.dll

Other dlls are working fine.

Exception:

```
assembly.GetTypes() 'assembly.GetTypes()' threw an exception of type 'System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException'    System.Type[] {System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException}
```

Can some one please let me know what might be issue with these dlls.
Please suggest some work around.

Comment: Perhaps you are missing a dependancy of the assembly, or you are using an older version of .NET and the assembly needs a newer version of .NET. `Assembly.Load` fully loads and integrates the assembly in your running app. For this reason apps like ILSpy don't use reflection but use Mono.Cecil to load assemblies.

Answer (score 0):

EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll has a dependancy on EntityFramework.dll.

Probably, this one is not located in the same path.

Try to put "EntityFramework.dll" in the same path, and it will work.

I suppose it's the same issue for the other DLL.

Comment: I am not facing issue with Enitity Framework.dll and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Core.dll which are located in the same path.